# batch file writing changed files of a git commit into variables

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd, git-commit

I would like to write a batch script (and run it via cmd) which writes the changed files of a specific git commit into variables.

I have got the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=1
for %%m in ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r sha1-hash') do (
        set var!count!=%%m 
        set /a count=!count!+1
)
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
ENDLOCAL
```

The echo of var1 and var2 gives back:
    'git for var1
    and diff-tree for var2

If I add echo %var3% echo %var4% and so on, the result is the following:
'git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r sha1-hash' echo off echo off echo off...

So I guess my git diff-tree...-command is not seen as a command. Tried to fix it on my own, but had to surrender... Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to use `FOR /F`.  Also look at using the `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` options depending on what you want for output.

Comment: I using /F is a good solution, can you add some lines of your output result in your question ?

Comment: @Squashman thank you very much! Adding /F solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use the `/F` flag to loop through tokens in text.
- Use the `/L` flag to loop through a range of numbers.

Example:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set REVISION=HEAD
set count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%m in ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %REVISION%') do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
    set var!count!=%%m
)

for /L %%i in (1, 1, %count%) do (
    echo %%i: !var%%i!
)
```

See here for details: https://ss64.com/nt/for.html